# Includes no cargan en el explorador

Tags: html, dreamweaver

Tengo el sigiuiente código realizado en Dreamweaver siguiendo un tutorial para realizar includes de elementos html en otro archivo. Aunque en dream se ven bien, cuando pruebo en el explorador no abren.

Include.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Include</title>
<link rel="import" href="content.html">
</head>
<body>
<div>
<script>
var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]');
var content = link.import;

// Grab DOM from warning.html's document.
var el = content.querySelector('.warning');

document.body.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

content.html

```
<div class="warning">
<style>
h3 {
  color: red !important;
}
</style>
<h3>Warning!</h3>
<p>This page is under construction</p>
</div>

<div class="outdated">
<h3>Heads up!</h3>
<p>This content may be out of date</p>
</div>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

`<link rel="import" ... >` **NO** funciona en todos los navegadores.

Para salir de dudas, este código te indica si el navegador que estas usando soporta o no los *imports*; es válido para todos: de escritorio, móviles, ...

```
if( 'import' in document.createElement( 'link' ) ) {
  alert( 'SI soportamos import' );
} else {
  alert( 'NO soportamos import' );
}
```

Logicamente, si tu navegador no los soporta, pues ... eso, que no podrás usarlos xD.

De entrada, si estas con Explorer, *instalate un navegador*.

Comment: Dado que no es soportado por todos los navegadores, no deberías usar este método para incluir un un archivo dentro de otro.

Comment: Ese comentario es a la respuesta ? ¿ no, verdad ?

Comment: Es un comentario al usuario que realiza la pregunta, haciendo referencia a tu respuesta, ya que como bien has dicho, este método de inclusión de archivos html dentro de otro no es soportado por algunos navegadores, pues quizás debería de usar otro método para incluir archivos dentro de otros.

Comment: Ok. Al verlo debajo de la respuesta, *crei* que era para mi. Yo los suelo poner *debajo* de la pregunta :-)

Comment: Hola!, @Trauma gracias por responder. Tengo 4 navegadores instalados y con ninguno corre. Exactamente en qué parte debo ubicar el código que me sugieres?

Comment: Donde quieras :-) dentro de un tag `<script> ... </script>`, claro. Lo único que hace es mostrarte una ventanita con el **si** o el **no**.

Comment: Listo! Sí somportamos! @Trauma

Comment: Pués ahora, a esperar que alguien con mas conocimientos que yo en *HTML includes* te responda. Yo ya no llego mas.